# Displaying data in Laravel DataTable

Tags: php, laravel, datatables

This is how my normal html table looked like. In the table, i display the countries as tabs and under every tab a user clicks, the tables displays teams that belong to the particular country(tab). This works fine.

```
      <div  class="nav-tabs-custom" id="tabs">

        <ul id="myUL" class="nav nav-tabs">
        @foreach($countries as $country)

           <li ><a href="#tab_{{ $country->id }}" data-toggle="tab" >{!!$country->name!!}</a></li>
           @endforeach


        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
        @foreach($countries as $key => $country)

          <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_{{ $country->id }}">
          <table class="table" id="tables">
                            <thead>
                                <tr> 
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th colspan="5"></th>
                                    <th></th>
                                </tr>
                           </thead>
                           <tbody id="list">
           @foreach($country->teams as $team) 
                           <td><input onclick="return show(this)" data-team="{{$team->toJson()}}" type="checkbox" id="{!! $team->id !!}" name="{!! $team->name !!}" value="{!! $team->value !!}" /> </td>
                                    <td width="600">{{$team->name }}</td>
                                     <td>{{ $team->value}}</td>
                                </tr>
          @endforeach        
       </tbody>
       </table>
         </div>
        @endforeach     
          </div>    

        </div>
```

But now, i am new to datatables and i am trying to convert the html to datatables as below

```
      <div  class="nav-tabs-custom" id="tabs">

        <ul id="myUL" class="nav nav-tabs">
        @foreach($countries as $country)

           <li ><a href="#tab_{{ $country->id }}" data-toggle="tab" >{!!$country->name!!}</a></li>
           @endforeach


        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
        @foreach($countries as $key => $country)

          <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_{{ $country->id }}">
          <table class="table" id="tables">
                            <thead>
                                <tr> 
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th colspan="5"></th>
                                    <th></th>
                                </tr>
                           </thead>

       </table>
         </div>
        @endforeach     
          </div>    

        </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

        oTable = $('#tables').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "bProcessing":false,
            "bSort":false,
            "ajax": "{{ route('datatable.findteam') }}",
            "columns": [
                {data: 'check', name: 'check', orderable: false, searchable: false},    
                {data: 'team_name', name: 'team_name'},  
                {data: 'team_value', name: 'team_value'},
          ],        
        });

});
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
 public function create()
     {
         $countries = Country::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
         return view('create',compact('countries'));
     }

     public function getTeams()
     {
        $countries = Country::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->get();    

        return Datatables::of($countries)->addColumn('check', function ($country) {
            foreach($country->teams as $team){

            return '
            <input onclick="return show(this)" data-team="{{$team->toJson()}}" type="checkbox" id="{!! $team->id !!}" name="{!! $team->name !!}" value="{!! $team->value !!}" />
            ';
            } 
            })->addColumn('team_name', function ($country) {
                foreach($country->teams as $team){
                 return $team->name;
                }
            })->addColumn('team_value', function ($country) {
                foreach($country->teams as $team){                    
                return  $team->value;

                }
            })

->make(true); 
     }
```

Now my issue is, when i run my project, it only fetches the first team for each  country and place them under the first country in the tab showing on the table.  How can i make it work like the how it was working in the normal html table above?

Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: `Country::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->get();` so your countries `id` column refers to  `user_id`?

Comment: @dexterb, yes it does and that is what i used with my `normal html table` which worked fine

Comment: try using eager loading on your builder. I updated my answer below

Comment: @dexterb  I am suspecting the fact that in my `create` function i retrieve countries and send to the view and in my `getTeams` function, i also retrieve countries and send to the view at the same time

Comment: @davidkonrad, i already tagged `datatables` or?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm right you are actually trying to put your teams table on a DataTable.
Then this should work for you

```
public function getTeams($country_id) {
    $teams = Team::where('country_id', $country_id);

    return Datatables::of($teams)
        ->addColumn('check', function (Team $team) {
            return '<input onclick="return show(this)" data-team="'.$team->toJson().'" type="checkbox" id="'.$team->id.'" name="'.$team->name.'" value="'.$team->value.'" />
                ';
        })->addColumn('team_name', function (Team $team) {
            return $team->name;
        })->addColumn('team_value', function (Team $team) {                  
            return  $team->value;
        })
        ->rawColumns([x])// x the index for your check column,
        ->make(true); 
}
```

**when i run my project, it only fetches the first team for each country and place them under the first country in the tab showing on the table** - this is because on your `addColumn` you loop through the teams in a country and immediately return the team name.

```
->addColumn('team_name', function ($country) {
    foreach($country->teams as $team){
        return $team->name; // this team will immediately return as the
                            // value of team_name, that's why you only get
                            //  the first team
    }
}
```

Comment: i get this error `[2017-12-17 09:18:08] local.ERROR: Use of undefined constant x - assumed 'x' {"userId":2,"email":"example@gmail.com","exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Use of undefined constant x - assumed 'x' at /Users/emmnock/FastFoodOderSystem/app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php:64)
`

Comment: replace with the index value of your new "check" column.
if your team has 6 (id, name,country_id,created_at, updated_at) original attributes, then x will be 6.

Comment: I do not understand your statement please

Comment: when counting the index you'll start at 0, so if your teams table have 6 columns, then its last index is 5, so in that case if you do `addColumn` on datatable, "check" will be on the index 6, so use it like this: `->rawColumns([6])`

Comment: `$teams = Country::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->teams();`  the `teams()` in this line gives an error

Comment: if `->teams()` gives an error, then there's something wrong on the relationship between your Country and Team tables. So, use this `Team::where('country_id', Auth::user()->id);` instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161391/discussion-between-dexterb-and-xamarindevil).